# Sumproduct between dates with additional criteria across columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to put together a sumproduct formula that looks between two dates and has a criteria across columns.

I have the following:

Start Date:
`Sheet1!A1`

End Date:
`Sheet1!A2`

Criteria Field: `Sheet1!A3`

I want to sum columns `Sheet2!B2:F200` where `Sheet2!A2:A200` is between the Start and End dates on `Sheet1` and where `Sheet2!B1:F1` equal the criteria field from `Sheet1`

I made it to here but I'm not able to sum across columns or add in the criteria field.

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!A2:A200>=Sheet1!A1),--(Sheet2!A2:A200<=Sheet1!A2),Sheet2!C:C)
```

Comment: are the column names in B1:F1 unique?

Comment: Yes they are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS with INDEX to return the correct column:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$F,0,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!$B1:$F$1,0)),Sheet2!$A:$A,">=" & Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,"<=" & Sheet1!A2)
```